# How to define WordPress plugin shortcode globally for multisite?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

I have a multisite project in which I have WordPress networked multi site.

In my site I have many of the plugins like photo gallery, video gallery, and widget.

I have created shortcode and I use them in the first site. But in other site it is not working. So I wanted to know the solution. How I can use the same shortcode for all the website?

My all website theme is same.

Comment: You have to enable a plugin on all sites to use it on all sites

Comment: @Tom is correct. The plugin must be enabled on all sub-sites or it won't work on that sub-site. (Been there, done that, spent several days before the "Doh!' moment.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to create a `Network-only` plugin that is Active for all the sites in the network and define your `shortcodes` inside.

To make specific plugin `Network-only` you need to add `Network: True` to your plugin definition, just like the example below.

Change:

```
/*
Plugin Name: My Awesome Plugin
Plugin URI: http://yourplugin.com/
Description: This is my extremely awesome WordPress plugin
Version: 1.0
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://yourcompany.com
License: GPLv2
*/
```

to the following:

```
/*
Plugin Name: My Awesome Plugin
Plugin URI: http://yourplugin.com/
Description: This is my extremely awesome WordPress plugin
Version: 1.0
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://yourcompany.com
License: GPLv2
Network: True
*/
```

After this is done make sure you activate your plugin from the `Network Admin` and the shortcodes defined in your plugin should work on all the sites in the network.